# What is MLP distribution in my statments?

Tags: stocks

So I was looking at my account statements and I see this column:

```
INCOME AND EXPENSE SUMMARY:
MLP DISTRIBUTION (reported by partnership) : THIS PERIOD $134  YEAR TO DATE $134
```

[MLP image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc9hN.png)

But I don't even know what is MLP and I never do anything with it, so what is this mean ? Is it my income, or is it my expense.
I read about MLP in many websites but it is too hard to understand.
Thank you

Comment: You bought shares in a publicly traded Partnership.  And it distributed $134.  What am I missing?

Comment: I still don't understand, what do you mean by it "distributed $134" ?
Do you mean my share is worth $134 ? Or do you mean they gave me $134 cash? Because I never received the $134 cash.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distribution "the act or process of distributing"  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distribute "to divide among several or many : APPORTION"  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apportion "**to divide and share out according to a plan**"

Comment: Thus, if you don't see the $134, *that* should be your question.

Comment: Thank You, I understand now. So basically it means that MLP Distribution = Dividend.
So I got $134 dollar dividend.
They make it hard to understand, they should just say: Dividend = $134

Comment: It's *functionally similar to* a dividend, but not a dividend, because only corporations issue dividends.

Comment: @savemightlife They can't call it a dividend because _it isn't a dividend_. It's _like_ a dividend but has different [tax treatment](https://www.simplysafedividends.com/intelligent-income/posts/9-a-guide-to-investing-in-master-limited-partnerships-mlps).